# Distance between nodes in a graph using bfs

Tags: c

I've written the following code:

```
void bfs(graph *g, int start)
{
    int i;
    int visited[MAXVERTS], next;
    for (i = 0; i < g -> nodes; i++)
        visited[i] = 0;
    visited[start] = 1;
    printf("%d", start);
    queuePtr q;
    q = QueueCreate();
    QueueEnter(q,start);
    while(!QueueIsEmpty(q))
    {
        next=QueueDelete(q);
        node *p=g->adjList[next];
        while(p)
        {  
            if(!visited[p->index])  
                visited[p->index] = 1;  
            QueueEnter(q,p->index);  
        }  
        p=p->link;  
    }  
}
```

What do I need to add to make it calculate the distance between two nodes in a graph?
I've been trying and I can't get it to work.

Comment: Are you looking for the shortest path between 2 nodes ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I implemented that same code some time ago, but can't find it. Amyway, the [Dijkstra's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) algorithm is what you need.

Cheers.